# Is it safe to remove "received" header?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

Is it safe to remove "received" fields created by my mail server for all outgoing mail? For example like this (all "received" headers from my server are deleted by postfix "smtp_header"checks"):

```
Received: from mxfront8j.mail.yandex.net ([127.0.0.1])
    by mxfront8j.mail.yandex.net with LMTP id J27O5Fv0
    for <xxxx@yandex.ru>; Thu, 27 Nov 2014 20:19:02 +0300
Received: from mx-01.example.net (mx-01.example.net [x.x.x.x])
    by mxfront8j.mail.yandex.net (nwsmtp/Yandex) with ESMTPS id kPMcIMmunV-J168XFhY;
    Thu, 27 Nov 2014 20:19:01 +0300
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits))
    (Client certificate not present)
X-Yandex-Front: mxfront8j.mail.yandex.net
X-Yandex-TimeMark: 1417108741
X-Yandex-Uniq: d21a5844-4df7-4e6f-b8d1-05765c0e780a
Authentication-Results: mxfront8j.mail.yandex.net; spf=pass (mxfront8j.mail.yandex.net: domain of example.com designates x.x.x.x as permitted sender) smtp.mail=postmaster@example.com; dkim=pass header.i=@example.com
From: postmaster <postmaster@example.com>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: check
Message-Id: <0FFFD42C-6F1C-439E-8932-FFBEA45A2106@example.com>
Date: Thu, 27 Nov 2014 21:18:58 +0400
To: XXXX <xxxx@yandex.ru>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Return-Path: postmaster@example.com
X-Yandex-Forward: b32ac2efb2ec233999e4d252a85c4037

check
```

Safe from the spam filters and etc.

Comment: In principle there's no problem with removing previous Received: header lines, but you're making it more difficult to trace problems when e.g. it occurs that spam is being sent through your system and you can't see in the headers where that message originated from inside your network.

Answer (score 1):

It is neither recommended nor common to remove received headers.  However, there are cases where it is desirable to remove the headers in an attempt to prevent leakage of your network configuration.  (This may not be as successful as intended.).

If you are removing headers, it is recommended you keep a record of the removed headers so that they can be matched up with the message.  The received headers can be invaluable in tracing error conditions.